# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView in Custom Adapter

Tags: android

I build custom arrayAdapter to show a progress bar into spinner, my xml for row be like this

```
<ProgressBar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/progressBar"
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and my custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter 
{

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource,textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_spinner_progress,parent,false);
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I initialize it

```
transferSpinner.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.default_spinner_progress,R.id.progressBar));
```

I got this error in stack trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com..debug, PID: 9537
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Comment: array adapter uses textview only. For other views you have to implement your custom adapter

Comment: yes, I use custom adapter as you see, but still get same error

Comment: Not custom array adapter . Create your adapter using base adapter class

Comment: I get you, It works thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `BaseAdapter` instead

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_spinner_progress, parent, false);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

call it using: `transferSpinner.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));`